# Google translate Api v2

Tags: javascript, google-translate

How do I get the translated sourcetext value from the [google sample "rest from javascript"](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) into the formfield so I can post the value to another destination.

```
<form name="somename" method="post" action="domsome.asp">
  Some text: <input type="text" name="sometext" value="translated_sourcetext"/><br />
  <input type=submit value=Accept id=submit1 name=submit1>
  <input type="button">
</form>
```

Comment: thx, I have tried the following by appending trans1 to the last line document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript); and document.write (trans1) between script tags but that didnt't work

Comment: Can you show us the complete source code of what you have?

Comment: // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
    trans1=  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
 
 <form name="somename" method="post" action="domsome.asp">
  Some text: <input type=hidden name="sometext" value="<script>document.write (trans1) </script>"/><br />
  <input type=submit value=Accept id=submit1 name=submit1>
  <input type="button">
</form>

Comment: the google sample code with the last line changed by assigning a variable(string) with the form fields. Purpose is to hide form field and have the value displayed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do you have the `translateText` callback parameter and function in place as shown in the example doc, you should be able to change the callback to:

```
<script>
  function translateText(response) {
    document.somename.sometext.value = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
```

EDIT:

From the [example](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html), find this:

```
<script>
  function translateText(response) {
    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
```

Change it to this:

```
<script>
  function translateText(response) {
    document.somename.sometext.value = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
```

So, rather than setting the innerhtml of a div, we are setting the value of your form input, as described in the question.

Comment: hmm thx I don't get this - how do i get the translated value in <input type=hidden name="sometext" value=show-the-translated-value</script>"/>

Comment: aha now I see and understand. The javascript accesses the DOM.
Thank you very much.